SOLIDWORKS: Is there a way to convert a Section View into a new part?
I hope this is the correct place for this question.
BLUF: is there a way in SOLIDWORKS to convert a Section View of a part into its own new part; alternatively, which features/tools of SOLIDWORKS could I use to do what I'm describing?
I'm a n00b when it comes to SOLIDWORKS, but after all my searching I've been unable to find a solution to what I'm trying to do.
I have a part that we've manufactured at work that is essentially a case for componentry. After having the prototype manufactured, however, we noticed that there are two screw holes that need chamfers that don't have them. I was able to add the chamfers to the screw holes with no issues, but we want to test the edits to the design before we have the case manufactured again, so we were going to 3d-print the model with the changes. However, the changes are only to a very small portion of the overall design, and we're not making changes everywhere else, so we don't want to waste material by printing the entire case. As such, I've been tasked with making a version of the part that's a small section of the part.
For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to do this.
I've seen numerous sites describing how to create Section Views, and I'm able to use it to... make the View, lol. But nowhere could I find anything even remotely like my request; is it because what I'm trying to do is trivial? Anywho, any help would be greatly appreciated.

not a solidworks user, but abstract procedure - if you can convert the view within the drawing to a sketch - I think SW can do that - and then copy the resulting sketch into a new part's main feature, eg an extrude or revolve or swept section?

alternatively, you could copy your original part's solid model, and add another feature to the model which cuts away everything except the part of it relevant to your experiment, and fabricate just that . . .

Okay, I've made progress: I used the Slice tool to create Sketches and Planes, then used the Extrude Cut tool along a Plane in two axes to separate the section I want from the rest of the part. However, when I try to delete the extra bits now, it still deletes everything, like they're still all connected.

It sounds like you are asking a about a XY problem. Brep models are indeed connected even if you cut out stuff.
